# 'Half-sifting' of Dirac Delta

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Is the solution of the following integral $0$ or $1$ or something else? And why so?

$$ \int_{0}^{t} f(\tau) \;\delta(\tau) \;d\tau$$

with

$\;\;\;t \in \mathbb{R}\,,\; f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\;\;\;f$ continuous

$\;\;\;\delta(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}+\infty\;\;for\,\,x=0\\0\;\;\;\;\;\, for\,\,x\neq0\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: You mean $f : \Bbb{R\to R}$. At first $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\delta(x)dx= g(0)$ is defined only for $g $ continuous, or continuous on some interval around $0$. You can extend it to every $g$ with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\delta(x)dx \overset{def}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \frac{1_{x\in [-1/n,1/n}]}{2n}dx$ in which case for $g$ piecewise continuous the limit converges to $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2}$. With $g(x) = f(x) 1_{x \in (0,t)}$ you get your result.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with $1_{x\in(0,t)}$ notation, is it $1 \;\;for\;\; x\in(0,t)$ and $0\;\;elsewhere$ ?

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta. Yes, with $1_{x\in(0,t)}$ **reuns** means
$$x \mapsto \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x\in(0,t)\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: So solution proposed by reuns would be $\frac{f(0)}{2}$, am i correct?